# Is there an inductive proof of commuting vector fields being coordinate vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry

The usual proof of the Frobenius integrability theorem in its vectorial form (i.e. about distributions, rather than Pfaffian ideals or systems of total differential equations) goes as follows:

1. Given a set of $n$ pointwise linearly independent vector fields $X_1,\dots, X_n$ in an $m$ dimensional manifold $M$ ($n\le m$) that satisfy $$ [X_a,X_b]=\sum_{c=1}^{n}C^c_{ab}X_c $$ one shows that there is an equivalent system $Y_1,\dots,Y_n$ (having the same span) with $[Y_a,Y_b]=0$.
2. One shows that if $Y_1,\dots,Y_n$ is a pointwise independent system that pairwise commutes ($[Y_a,Y_b]=0$) then there is a coordinate system $x^1,\dots,x^m$ in some neighborhood of every point such that $Y_a=\partial/\partial x^a$ ($a=1,\dots,n$). Usually this proof is accomplished similar to the proof of the "straightening theorem" for a single vector field, i.e. a coordinate system is constructed through the joint flow of the system using the fact that for commuting vector fields, the flows also commute.

Let's say, for the sake of argument, that I don't like this flow-based proof and I want to show inductively that if $Y_1,\dots,Y_n$ is a pointwise independent pairwise commuting system, then they are the coordinate basis fields for some chart by noting that when $n=1$, this is just the straightening theorem, and performing induction on $n$.

In  [Sharpe's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387947329) and inductive proof of Frobenius' theorem is given using a similar approach. However Sharpe does not assume that the initial system pairwise commutes, only that it is in involution, and his proof consists of a step-by-step modification of the system $Y_1,\dots,Y_n$ to finally get a system equivalent to the initial one that pairwise commutes and are coordinate vector fields.

If we assume that they system pairwise commutes beforehand, then Sharpe's proof is simpler, but it still requires modification of the system, i.e. we pass from $Y_1,\dots,Y_n$ to a different but equivalent system $Z_1,\dots,Z_n$ which still commutes, but are coordinate vector fields.

So far I was unable to modify the proof so that the initial system $Y_1,\dots,Y_n$ is intact at the end of the process, or come up with an original proof.

---

So, the question is, is there an inductive proof that a system of independent, pairwise commuting vector fields consists of coordinate vector fields *without passing to a different system with the same span*? If so what is it or where can I find it?

Ideally I want this proof to completely avoid using flows except that we accept the results of the straightening theorem (i.e. that a nonzero vector field $X$ is of the form $X=\partial/\partial x^1$ for some coordinate system).

Comment: Did you try this with $n=2$?

Comment: I doubt it. But Wolfson/Chern have a clever inductive proof of Frobenius using no flows.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yeah I know that proof or a closely related variant (aside from the proof in Sharpe's book, there is also https://www.jstor.org/stable/2159499), however I hoped there is also a variant which keeps the initial system fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind?

Pick a point $p_0$. There exists a unique curve $p_1(t)$ such that
$$ p_1(0) = p_0\text{ and }p_1'(t) = Y_1(p_1(t)). $$ Next, through each point $p_1(y_1)$, there exists a unique curve $p_2(y_1,t)$ such that $$ p_2(y_1,0) = p_1(y_1)\text{ and }\partial_2p_2(y_1,t) = Y_2(p_2(y_1,t)). $$ Repeating this process, you get a map $p(y_1, \dots, y_n) \in M$ that satisfies:
\begin{align*}
\partial_1p(y_1, 0,\dots, 0) &= Y_1(p(y_1,0,\dots, 0))\\
\partial_2p(y_1, y_2, 0, \dots, 0) &= Y_2(p(y_1,y_2,0,\dots, 0))\\ & \vdots\\
\partial_np(y_1, \dots, y_n) &= Y_n(p(y_1, \dots, y_n)).
\end{align*}
Using the fact that partials commute and so do $Y_1$ and $Y_2$, you check that
$$
\partial_2(\partial_1p(y_1,y_2,0,\dots, 0) - Y_1(p(y_1,y_2,0,\dots, 0))) = 0.
$$
This and the first equation in the system above imply that
$$
\partial_1p(y_1,y_2,0,\dots, 0) - Y_1(p(y_1,y_2,0, \dots, 0)) = 0.
$$
Keep doing this until you finally get for each $1 \le k \le n$,
$$
\partial_kp(y_1, \dots, p_n) = Y_k(p(y_1, \dots, y_m)).
$$

Comment: Not precisely what I had in mind, but seems like a nice proof that completely suffices for my purposes!